# Vertically center a header on top of an image

Tags: html, css, image, header, positioning

I'm trying to vertically center an `h2` on top of an `img`, but I can't get it exactly centered. I'm almost there, but how do I get it exactly there?

Details:

- I don't know the height of any of the elements, so I can't use fixed heights and setting the image as a background is not an option because the image is part of the content
- Some have suggested `display:table`, but I've tried it and it doesn't play nice with `position:relative` and `position:absolute`

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/gUKbAE" />
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Title</h2>   
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image { 
    position: relative; 
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 0;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I've put it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/15/

Comment: If you saw this question a while ago: I reformatted it so it better reflected my problem.

Comment: Instead of reposting, you should have reformatted your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not perfectly centered is because it is making the `top` of the line of text at `50%`.

Simple fix is changing the `line-height` to be `0px`:

```
.wrapper
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   line-height: 0px;
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! So simple, but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you set the font size of your h2, then you can just add a negative top-margin to your wrapper (or h2 I believe), like so...

```
.image { 
    position: relative; 
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -15px; /* Set negative margin here to pull it up */
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 30; /* Set font size here */
}
```

I made your h2 font-size 30 and then just set the .wrapper margin-top to -15 here.

Here it is on jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/15/